VS Code closes after opening
I just installed ubuntu 24.
I'm a django developer and I've been working fine with Visual Studio Code, but today when I tried to open my vscode, while it was opening it closed without any error or message! :(
I restarted my computer and reinstalled Vscode.
But nothing that nothing:(
note: I installed vscode from app center on ubuntu

Try to run it from command line. Error messages should appear in terminal if any.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78586544/836330 probably a duplicate.

I've faced the same issue. I think you've installed it from snap store. You need to install it with deb package. Uninstall the current code(remove it). Go to official website of Visual Studio Code, download the latest version and install it with command:
sudo dpkg -i code_1.90.0-1717531825_amd64.deb

In fact, the command is:
sudo dpkg -i <deb_file_name>.deb


Thank you my friend! my vscode is working well:D. I hope you get over all the Errors in your life$$

doesn't work in that the file picker on Kubuntu never opens and vscode hangs; same for chromium. This is a complete Kubunu-Wayland desaster.

Open vscode through the command line, and then you will get the full error message.
You can also see logs in ~/.config/Code/logs.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
