VSCode is not running after self-updating on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have installed Vscode using snap on my Ubuntu 24.04. It was okay and working, but vscode stopped working after self-updating today.
I have switched from Wayland to Xorg display server in Ubuntu and it still doesn't work.
I also have used code --verbose command and here is the long list of errors which I am putting some here:
[0606/131818.075710:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[6510:0606/131817.048208:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[6510:0606/131817.048275:ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[6510:0606/131817.048284:ERROR:gl_display.cc(786)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[6510:0606/131817.050936:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1052 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.

Starting VS Code
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.238Z] from: /snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.238Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  merge: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  'pre-release': false,
  'update-extensions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-lcd-text': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'disable-chromium-sandbox': false,
  sandbox: false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  'enable-smoke-test-driver': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'use-inmemory-secretstorage': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': 'e58fa900-15ff-4c34-ba40-8482f42505f4',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'preserve-env': false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  'disable-gpu-sandbox': false,
  '__enable-file-policy': false,
  'enable-coi': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  'disable-dev-shm-usage': false,
  'profile-temp': false,
  logsPath: '/home/hermione/.config/Code/logs/20240606T131817'
}
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.241Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.242Z] Resolved machine identifier: b5c1c8e60027fc6cd93c155256ec5ca2b12c03a46227117bb49f1881470321c6
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.243Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.253Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/hermione/.config/Code/User'
[main 2024-06-06T17:18:17.255Z] StorageMainService: creating application storage
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris




follow this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78586028/vs-code-closes-after-opening/

Thank you very much. Installing it using dpkg command worked for me too.
